# Blazor connect to service with external database

Tags: c#, mariadb, blazor, .net-6.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am currently trying with Blazor server to get a list. But when the list is called via the service I just get an error:

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
> ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
> at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 433
> at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 363

i am currently calling in the Program.cs:
`builder.Services.AddScoped<Organization>().AddDbContext<OrganizationDbContext>().AddEntityFrameworkMySql();`

then i try to inject the Organization.

in the Organization there is:

```
public Organization()
{
     this.organizationDBContext = new OrganizationDbContext();
}
```

so the funny part about all that is in the unit test the external project works just perfect(also if i call new Organization in the OnInitializedAsync sometime it works sometime it doesn't idk why).

My unit test which works perfectly fine:

```
Organization org = new Organization();
var customers = org.Customers.GetCustomers().ToList();
```

i get a list with the customers, how should i do this in blazor server?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all of you who have the same error, this is the right way, keep an eye on your docker environment^^

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).